# Django unique_together versus explicit duplicate restriction

Tags: python, django

I currently have this try-except block to restrict duplication of user and post fields in Follow model:

```
def follow(request, post_pk):
    user = request.user
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_pk)
    try:
        _follow = Follow.objects.get(user=user, post=post)
    except Follow.DoesNotExist:
        _follow = Follow(user=user, post=post)
        _follow.save()
    return redirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))
```

I recently just learned about unique_together in class Meta. Now, I can modify the model like this:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'post'),)
```

Having done so, is it safe to remove the explicit duplicate restriction in try-block of views.py? The code will then look like this:

```
def follow(request, post_pk):
    user = request.user
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_pk)
    _follow = Follow(user=user, post=post)
    _follow.save()
    return redirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *unique_together* you have added a constraint to your DB.
If you perform `_follow.save()` and the post-user combo exists in the db, the application raise a IntegrityError exception.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

def follow(request, post_pk):
    user = request.user
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_pk)
    try:
        Follow.objects.create(user=user, post=post)
    except IntegrityError: 
        # do something to manage duplicate? or show error and redirect
    return redirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))
```